# Changing version with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, versioning

I am looking to change versions of an .sde through Arcpy to then afterwards,  run a few geoprocesses on it. I do not want it to automatically update after that.

So far I have managed to create a version through ArcPy, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to connect to it. The "Changeversion_management" only does this on 1 feature class and keeps throwing me errors such as the following:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Feature Layer or Table View: Dataset ZN_KGD@pkgd.sde does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (ChangeVersion).
```

And

```
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of ZN_KGD.ExPimp_p9 | ZN_KGD.Tool_test
Failed to execute (ChangeVersion).
```

I would like to change the version of all the feature classes in the TOC, or at least connected to the same .sde. The script I am using to create and change the version is the following:

```
import arcpy

Project_number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

inWorkspace = "C:/Users/Lansr/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.3/ArcCatalog/ZN_KGD@pkgd.sde"
parentVersion = "ZN_KGD_DIENSTVERSIE"

# Execute CreateVersion
arcpy.CreateVersion_management(inWorkspace, parentVersion, "ExPimp_{}".format(Project_number), "PUBLIC")

arcpy.ChangeVersion_management('ZN_KGD.ZN_KGD_DIENSTVERSIE',
                               'TRANSACTIONAL',
                               "ExPimp_{}".format(Project_number),
                               '')
```

The feature layer and sde are not defined in the script, but are purely in the TOC.

It is important to note that the top error happens when I fill in the name of the .sde and the bottom error happens when I fill in the name of a feature layer. My knowledge of ArcPy is limited at best. I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to show where you create your version and also how `Deklaag_vlakken` and `ZN_KGD@pkgd.sde` are defined.

Comment: My apologies, I have editted the question, hopefully this is enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around this by doing the following:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping

Project_number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
inWorkspace = "C:/Users/Lansr/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.3/ArcCatalog/ZN_KGD@pkgd.sde"
parentVersion = "ZN_KGD_DIENSTVERSIE"

# Execute CreateVersion
arcpy.CreateVersion_management(inWorkspace, parentVersion, "ExPimp_{}".format(Project_number), "PUBLIC")

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("G:\\zn\\NM\\GGB\\Applicaties-Admin\\Kerngis\\ExpImp\\{}\\{}.mxd".format(Project_number, Project_number))  # Uses your currently open MXD
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, ''): # Loop through dataframes
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers


        arcpy.ChangeVersion_management  (lyr.name,
                                        "TRANSACTIONAL",
                                        "ZN_KGD.ExPimp_{}".format(Project_number),
                                        '')
```